# Hapi good logging depends on the enviroment

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Is there a way to enable / disable
depends on the enviroment in good ?

For instance I'd like to run this
only when NODE_ENV is equal to develepement

```
var goodOptions = {
    opsInterval: 1000,
    reporters: [{
        reporter: require('good-console'),
        events: {log: '*', response: '*' , error: '*' , request: '*'}
    }]
};

server.register({
    register: require('good'),
    options: goodOptions
},
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
);
```

no ternary operator :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just add:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    goodOptions.reporters = [];
}
```

If you start getting into complex configuration then you should take a look at [hapijs/confidence](https://github.com/hapijs/confidence) which is a really powerful configuration tool. It would be overkill just for this though.

Comment: In hapi 13.4.1 reporters is an object:

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    goodOptions.reporters = {};
}